flutter http.post causes the web client to crash
When I attempt a basic http post, I can see that the server is returning a normal 400. But the client seems to just crash with an error I can't make sense of. I have the following code
static Future<TradApiServerResponse> submitPhone(
  String phone, String code) async {
    http.Response response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("$urlbase/api/submitphone"),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'code': code,
        'phone': phone,
      }),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {

When stepping trough it never gets to the if statement. It just locks up then crashes. The server is responding. I can curl or use the browser directly and it works fine
Error
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 329:10  createErrorWithStack
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 265:28            _throw
dart-sdk/lib/core/errors.dart 120:5                                           throwWithStackTrace
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1386:11                                          callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:7            <fn>
Application finished.

How can I figure out what the problem is? Sorry I am new to flutter.
when wrapped in a try statement
ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error., uri=http://127.0.0.1/api/submitphone

One thing I noticed when the request is captured over wireshark it is request method "OPTIONS" instead of POST ??
UPDATE: this happens in the most basic version possible
http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse("http://127.0.0.1"),);

line crashes even when a 200 is returned. I tested against
python -m http.server 80

There must be something really stupid and obvious I am doing? This is running on the web version using chrom

Can you add try catch to you entire code and see if any HTTP exceptions are thrown.

@BhaveshAudichya ok sorry it took me a bit to get the error. I wanted to switch the server to a local machine so I could packet capture

This is a standard CORS error because your server isn't emitting any CORS headers. Eventually, if you host your web app from the same server (and port number) as your backend, you will not have a problem. However, during debugging your flutter web application is not launched from the same port as your backend is running at. This leads to the CORS error. Either add CORS headers to your back end during debugging, or disable checking in Chrome. (There are a bunch of answers in SO for the latter.)

ohh I didn't even think about that thank you!

Thanks to @Richard Heap. The issue was CORS. The docs for what your server need to do are here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
a low level python wsgi implementation is shows here so you can see exactly what to do
def handler(environ, start_response):
    method = environ["REQUEST_METHOD"]
    origin = environ.get("HTTP_ORIGIN")
    cookie = environ.get("HTTP_COOKIE", "N/A")
    
    cors = origin
    preflight = cors and method == "OPTIONS"

    headers = [("Content-Type", "text/plain")]
    if cors:
        headers.extend([
            ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin),
            ("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        ])
        if preflight:
            headers.extend([
                ("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST"),
                ("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
            ])
    else:
        headers.append(("Set-Cookie", "auth=fnd"))

    if method == "OPTIONS":
        start_response("204 No Content", headers)
        return []
    else:
        start_response("200 OK", headers)
        return ["Cookie: ", cookie]

Credit https://gist.github.com/FND/204ba41bf6ae485965ef
